# Un-install service/apk from phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk

For testing purposes I installed a service on Android Phone from Eclipse i.e instead of running from emulator I used my phone.

This service is invoked by Alarm Manager every 5 minutes, creates an entry in a text file in sdcard folder and closes. So most of time its not running and can't be detected by Tools that manage apps.

I know the app/service is running as entries are made to the text file every 5 minstes.

**How Can I locate and delete this apk/service from my phone?**

```
C:\Windows\System32>adb devices
List of devices attached
304D191DFA60186E        device


C:\Windows\System32>adb shell
$ adb uninstall com.majeedk.Alarm
adb uninstall com.majeedk.Alarm
adb: not found
$
```

I tried the above and it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from command prompt run:

```
 adb uninstall yourpackage
```

Comment: My APK is names Alarm.apk and package is named com.majeedk.Alarm Which one of these do I have to use.

Comment: 'C:\Windows\System32>adb devices                                       
List of devices attached
304D191DFA60186E        device

C:\Windows\System32>adb shell
$ adb uninstall com.majeedk.Alarm
adb uninstall com.majeedk.Alarm
adb: not found
$'                                                                    What Shall I do

Comment: C:\Windows\System32>adb uninstall com.majeedk.Alarm run it in this way.